# Making an immitation "Craigslist Program" - how can I seperate results from inputs?

Tags: macos, virtual, box

I am writing an imitation craigslist project. I need to ask a user if they want to: 
1. Enter a product 
2. Buy a product

When the user types 1, they are asked if they want to sell a (b)ike or a (t)ruck, they give an input, and are then asked for a price. 
I used append to add this to a list.

However, I can't get the inputs for if a user types "2" to work, 
it completely disregards what I have asked it to print if the user types "2" and instead asks if they want to sell a (b)ike or (t)ruck.

heres a look at my code :

```
play = True
productList =[['bike', 50]] #supposed to be a bike on the list already

print "Would you like to:" 
print "1. Add an item."
print "2. Find an item."

choice = raw_input ("Enter your selection")

while play: 
    if choice == "1":
    play = True
    print "What would you like to sell, a bike or truck?"
    item = raw_input ("enter the item type, b or t.)

    elif item == "b":
        price = raw_input ("enter item cost:")
        bikePrice = "bike" ,price
        productList.append (bikePrice)
        print "Your product has been added to Craigslist"
    elif item == "t":
        price = raw_input ("enter item cost:"
        bikePrice = "bike" ,price
        productList.append (bikePrice)
        print "Your product has been added to Craigslist"

if choice == "2":
    play = True 
    print "yay"
```

so essentially, the program completely disregards the fact that when I type a "2" it is supposed to print yay. How can I make my program only show the options for "Enter a item" (1) if the user types (1), and only show the options for "Find an item" (2) if the user types (2)?

I know there is an easy fix to this, but I'm two weeks into coding and very clueless :) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned things up a bit to get it running. Notice where I set `play` to `False` so that you don't have an infinite loop.

```
play = True
productList =[['bike', 50]] #supposed to be a bike on the list already

print "Would you like to:" 
print "1. Add an item."
print "2. Find an item."

choice = raw_input ("Enter your selection")

while play: 
    if choice == "1":
        play = False
        print "What would you like to sell, a bike or truck?"
        item = raw_input ("enter the item type, b or t.")
        if item == "b":
            price = raw_input ("enter item cost:")
            bikePrice = ["bike", price]
            productList.append(bikePrice)
            print "Your product has been added to Craigslist"
        elif item == "t":
            price = raw_input ("enter item cost:")
            truckPrice = "truck", price
            productList.append(truckPrice)
            print "Your product has been added to Craigslist"
    if choice == "2":
        play = False 
        print "yay"
```